# Promise - `then()` not works as expect

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I do have 2 function. I am chaining with `then()` method for `promise`. But I am trying to initiate the `second` function after the first promise happend. But now the second function call as first. how to fix this?

or any issue with my code?

here is my try:

```
var getData = function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(42); //consoles as second
    }, 5000);
  })
}

var getDataMoreData = function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(43); //consoles as first
    }, 3000);
  })
}



getData().then((data)=> console.log('Data', data)).then(getDataMoreData().then((data)=> console.log('data--', data )));
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fywpw8dd/11/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.then` accepts a *function* as a parameter. When you do

```
.then(getDataMoreData()
  .then((data) => console.log('data--', data))
);
```

, it *immediately* calls `getDataMoreData()` (with the expectation that it will return a function that it can put into the promise chain). But `getDataMoreData` does not return a function - it returns a promise.

Any function *calls* immediately within a `then` get executed immediately, as it attempts to build the `.then` promise chain. Simply list the function variable inside the `then` instead of calling it:

```js
var getData = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(42); 
    }, 500);
  })
}

var getDataMoreData = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(43); 
    }, 300);
  })
}



getData()
  .then((data) => console.log('Data', data))
  .then(getDataMoreData)
  .then((data) => console.log('data--', data));
```

Comment: this answer is correct - as a side note, if you don't need serial execution, you can run them in parallel with: Promise.all([getData(), getMoreData()].then((data1, data2) => {})